# Flah не отображает текст в html блоках, которые над ним

Tags: flash, html, css, вёрстка

Клиент пожелал вместо картинки в шапке установить гигантский уродливый flash-баннер с анимацией, баннер установил, прописал ему wmode="opaque", и расположил над ним два блока - с текстом и с ссылками-иконками.

Дело в том, что блоки встали как надо поверх флеша, но вот текст в блоке не показывается, точнее текст показывается когда проблемному блоку задать явно цвет background. Как можно побороть этот баг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все разобрался, когда используешь wmode="opaque", нужно указать его так:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

и дописать атрибут для

```
<embed wmode="opaque"></embed>
```

После этого заработало